# Regex to match period followed by &nbsp; at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I match the **`.&nbsp;&nbsp;`** in the following HTML string?

```
<p>My first <strong>comment</strong>.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

The above string could have more than one **`&nbsp;`** at the end before the closing paragraph tag `</p>`.

Comment: it's not following , it's preceding. Also, what exactly should be matched?

Comment: This should work `/\.(?:&nbsp;)+/g`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `/\.(?:&nbsp;)+(?=[^.]*$)/g`.

```js
var str = '<p>.&nbsp;&nbsp; My first <strong>comment</strong>.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>';
console.log(str.replace(/\.(?:&nbsp;)+(?=[^.]*$)/g, 'test')); 
//"<p>.&nbsp;&nbsp; My first <strong>comment</strong>test</p>"
```